# How is sling:resourceSuperType is impacting sling resolution?

Tags: java, aem, sling

Hi was going through the how sling resolution works.

I came against this scenario which is mentioned on Adobe aem-developer guide

https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/the-basics.html

This is the scenario which is mentioned- 
/
a ( does not have any resource supertype or resource type)

b (sling:resourceSuperType = a)

c (sling:resourceSuperType = b)

x (sling:resourceType = c)

y (sling:resourceType = c, sling:resourceSuperType = a)

The type hierarchy of /x is [ c, b, a, ] while for /y the hierarchy is [ c, a, ] because /y has the sling:resourceSuperType property whereas /x does not and therefore its supertype is taken from its resource type.

now I understand how /x is resolved. But I am not sure about /y. first it resolved to /c. which itself had an sling:resourceSuperType as b. Should the sling resolution not go to /b as well. how is the supertype is overriden and resource is resolved to a instead of b.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in the [Apache Sling documentation](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/resources.html#resource-types), if a `sling:resourceSuperType` is defined for a particular resource, it will be used. If it's not present, the framework will use the `sling:resourceSuperType` defined by the resource pointed to by the `sling:resourceType`.

That said, in case of `/y`, `/b` will not be treated as a super type. The `sling:resourceSuperType` defined by `/y` itself points directly to `/a`. It will effectively hide the `sling:resourceSuperType` property defined at `/c` (and pointing at `/b`) that would otherwise be taken into account.

The example is quite well described on the very [documentation page](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/the-basics.html) you linked to.

In my experience, most custom AEM components are easier to maintain if the resource type hierarchy is defined by a set of nodes defining a component and present in the repository as descendants of `/apps` or `/libs` (when including OOTB components in the inheritance hierarchy). Specific instances of components (including ones responsible for rendering whole Pages) present in the `/content` sub-tree can then unambiguously define a `sling:resourceType` that determines its type (inheritance or not). Personally, I prefer not to define the `sling:superResourceType` at the level of a resource that's part of the `/content` sub-tree as it makes the hierarchy somewhat more difficult to reason about. Off the top of my head, I can't think of a use case that would justify this trade-off. Perhaps someone else could weigh in if they know a good one.

Comment: Thank you so much. I went through the  https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/resources.html#resource-types n number of times and read the lines but could not actually process what was written there. I had the same idea behind how its working but actually wanted to sure. Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation.

Comment: We also follow the same structure that you have suggested. The reason I came to point that I always thought that the once resource:type is found, it would ignore resourceSuperType since the former had more priority than latter. Clearly I was wrong then someone pointed out this example which needed me to understand how this is actually happening